# How to take action on content reading from QR Code Reader in Android?

Tags: android, qr-code

Here i develop an QR Code Reader app with the use of XZing Project library. it reads qr code and get content. But i take an action on Reading content. I read QR code with device and i get web URL now i open that Web URL Web Page in Android, If i read phone number it call on that number in Android.

please help me,
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried?

You'll get the response back like this

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    String contents = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"); //this is the result
}
```

You then have the contents as a string.

If it's a URL, you can do something like this to open it in a browser

```
Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
in.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(in);
```